# MySQL Second (or third) Index Of in String

Tags: mysql, indexof

What would be the simplest way to locate the index of the third space in a string.

My goal is to get `CCC` out of this space separated list: `AAAA BBBB CCCC DDDD EEE`. where A and B and D are fixed length, and C is variable length, E F G are optional.

In Java I would use indexof, with a starting point of 10 and that would get me the third space, but it seems that I cannot do that in MySQL, so I thought maybe I could find a 'third index of' function?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You would want to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ' ', 3), ' ', -1)
FROM table
```

The inner function call would get you to `AAAA BBBB CCCC` while the outer function call would pare that down to just `CCCC`.

Comment: Great explanation of how to get an index of an item by number.  So if I have a csv with 8 items I can now get any of those 8 by the number....Very nice thanks much man.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you can select the `nth` word in a string using:

```
SET @N = 3; -- 3rd word
SET @delimiter = ' ';
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(words, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)
FROM
  my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `Find_string_by_position`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION
`Find_string_by_position`(str VARCHAR(255), delimeter VARCHAR(255),pos INT(2)) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4 BEGIN
       DECLARE s VARCHAR(255);  
       DECLARE d VARCHAR(255); 
       DECLARE p INT DEFAULT 1;
       DECLARE val VARCHAR(255);


       SET s = LCASE(str); 
       SET d = delimeter;
       SET p = pos;
       SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(s,d,p),d,-1) INTO @val; 

       RETURN @val;  

   END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use below query to find any random id from table after group by.
Here id is the autoincrement_id.

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id),",",FLOOR(RAND()*COUNT(DISTINCT id))+1),",",-1) AS random_id FROM tableName GROUP BY groupbyColumn`

Answer (score 0):

| Id | Name | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amit Kumar Sharma | Computer Science |

*You can extract third string by simple query

Query :-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Name, ' ', -1) as last_name FROM table_name
```

Output :-
Sharma