# Is there a FIND_IN_SET by index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I know storing lists as strings is not wise, but I have to deal with that to export some data stored that way. I also know the `FIND_IN_SET` function, which returns the index of a certain string in a list:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('bar', 'foo,bar,baz');
-- selects 2
```

Is there any built-in function (or combination of functions) to get the string in a particular index of the list? I'm looking for something like this:

```
SELECT IN_SET_AT_INDEX(2, 'foo,bar,baz');
-- selects 'bar'
```

I'd like to avoid a split-like function that makes the list a separate table, if possible.

Comment: Use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function. There are examples on the documentation page.

Comment: I seem to have skipped that when going through the docs.

Comment: Also, I can't believe I couldn't find this question on SO already. If anyone knows a duplicate, I'll be glad to help close this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Second (or third) Index Of in String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347581/mysql-second-or-third-index-of-in-string)

Comment: I found one, but I had to know what solution I was looking for to find it.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I believe both questions should be connected, voted to close too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) can do this, sort of:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('foo,bar,baz', ',', 2), ',', -1) AS middle_one;
+------------+
| middle_one |
+------------+
| bar        |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using that. I knew there would be a way, but I was looking at the wrong place (stuff like ELT)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it requires just a little trickery.  The basis is `substring_index()`, but that gets everything up to the nth entry.  Then I use `reverse()` twice and another `substring_index()`:

```
select reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index('foo,bar,baz', ',', 2)), ',', 1))
```

In your case, the transformations are:

```
original string:                'foo,bar,baz'
after substring_index(..., 2)   'foo,bar'
after inner reverse             'rab,oof'
after substring_index(..., 1)   'rab'
after outer reverse             'bar'
```

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` can index from the end with negative indexes... why complicate things with `REVERSE()`?

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I'm going with SUBSTRING_INDEX twice, as it's just simpler.

Comment: @bfavaretto . . . I agree with you.  That is a better approach.  Somehow, I missed that very clear point in the documnetation on what happens with a negative index.