# MySQL: extracting the first, second and third word from a string (or varchar field)

Tags: mysql

How can I extract the **first** and the **second** words in a varchar field in **MySQL**?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SUBSTRING_INDEX ([official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), [official MariaDb Documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/substring_index/))

```
SELECT Substring_index(`sentence`, ' ', 1)                           AS first_word, 
       Substring_index(Substring_index(`sentence`, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS second_word,
       Substring_index(Substring_index(`sentence`, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) AS third_word 
FROM   `test`
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iSGActpsMNzHze13W2QA3q/1

It's also possible to make it more general with this solution:

```
SET @N = 3; --3rd word
SET @delimiter = ' ';
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sentence`, @delimiter, @N), @delimiter, -1)
FROM
  `test`;
```

[credits to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52165794/196210)

Comment: things are getting worse, now screenshots of [w3fools](https://web.archive.org/web/20110412103745/http://w3fools.com/) are getting included.. If you what to include something include a quote **only** of the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: this answer is a bit harsh. I think it's a matter of preference. In my opinion the evolution would be to share have this place reducing the effort of users more and more.

Comment: protecting you against possible downvotes, w3schools has a negative reputation around here for a good reason..  Also w3schools documention well never be that good then the official vendor documentations, iam pretty sure if we would search we still find mistakes/unlogical things there.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: thanks, I didn't know that. Let me check for another source.

Comment: *"Let me check for another source. "* Check mine first comment...

Comment: @SalmanA: sorry for the mistake, I've fixed the issue by pointing to the right website. Would you consider lifting away the downvote?

Comment: @RaymondNijland: would you like helping me to start this task? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56957297/mysql-procedure-to-split-a-string-into-words-and-search-if-they-are-all-containe