# How to extract specifc part from a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I am trying to extract a specifc part from a string in **MySQL**, however, I am unable to extract it correctly.

The pattern is the following:

```
-MB|{field_1}-AA|{field_2}-BB|{field_3}
```

This is the example

```
-MB|string1-AA|string2-BB|string3
```

I've written the following code to extract the last field, however it is not dynamic, and will only work, when we have a specific number of letters/numbers:

```
SELECT 
    test_string,
    SUBSTRING(test_string, LOCATE( '|', test_string) + 1 - LOCATE( '|', test_string) - 9) as string3
FROM test_table;
```

The output is the whole string and then just the last part of it:

**string3**

Having this said, can someone suggest a syntax that I can use in order to extract:

- the values between the 1st | and second |
- the value between the 2nd | and the 3rd |
- and a better way to extract everything after the 3rd |

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This probably answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347581/mysql-second-or-third-index-of-in-string

Comment: *extract the last field* `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '|', -1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for the last string only, you can `REVERSE()` the string first then locate `|` and then use it to do `SUBSTRING()` on the reversed string.. THEN reverse it again to get the original string. There are three `REVERSE()` in total if you're going with `SUBSTRING()` without a subquery:

```
SELECT test_string,
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(test_string),1,LOCATE('|',REVERSE(test_string))-1))
 FROM test_table;
```

If you're using a subquery, you can reduce the usage of `REVERSE()` to two, albeit with a longer query:

```
SELECT test_string,
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(rvstr,1,LOCATE('|',rvstr)-1))
  FROM
(SELECT test_string,
       REVERSE(test_string) rvstr
 FROM test_table) a;
```

But you can avoid all that and just use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT test_string,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string, '|', -1)
 FROM test_table;
```

You can use the same function to extract other string separated by the delimiter using something like this:

```
SELECT test_string,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',1),'|',-1) AS 'Str1',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',2),'|',-1) AS 'Str2',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',3),'|',-1) AS 'Str3'
 FROM test_table;
```

As for *"way to extract everything after the 3rd"*, I think it's a bit tricky but maybe:

```
SELECT test_string,
        Str1,Str2,Str3,
        SUBSTRING(test_string,LENGTH(CONCAT(Str1,Str2,Str3))+4) AS 'StrAfter3rd'
 FROM
(SELECT test_string,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',1),'|',-1) AS 'Str1',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',2),'|',-1) AS 'Str2',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_string,'|',3),'|',-1) AS 'Str3'
 FROM test_table) v;
```

Getting the `LENGTH()` of the concatenated results of `Str1` to `Str3` with 3 of the original `|` re-added and + the last `|` before the 4th string (`+4` in total), then use it for the `SUBSTRING()`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5cd2b2fa54f823e7e5772db16117a4e)